Как создать задержку между двумя анимациями в юнити?
Созданы две анимации: одна - закрытая дверь, затем дверь открывается, вторая - персонаж стоит, затем идет.
По нажатию кнопки происходит переход в обеих анимациях:
animator.SetTrigger("door1");
anim.SetTrigger("walk");

Как создать задержку по времени, чтобы вторая анимация (переход персонажа из стоя в ходьбу) осуществлялся после полного завершения первой анимации (открытие двери)?

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Вот что-то похожее через корутины https://stackoverflow.com/a/40587340/8324991

CrazyElf, спасибо. Пытаюсь разобраться.

В аниматоре в transition(стрелочка) есть Has Exit Time , то есть воспроизведение новой анимации не начнётся , пока не закончится другая.
Так же можно с помощью async.
Пример:
private async void AnimChanger()
{
    var animatinon = PlayerAnimator.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0)[0].clip;
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(animatinon.length));
}

